# Doctrine inheritance in Flow

Tags: doctrine-orm, flow-framework

I’m trying to set up a Base-class for my Typo3 Flow projects. It should contain the “created at” and the “updated at” date. 
Since Doctrine allows you to use inheritance mapping, I want to make my baseclass a “MappedSuperclass”.

BaseClass.php:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseClass {
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated;

    ...
```

Component.php:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class Component extends BaseClass{
```

If i try to use the "flow doctrine:update" command the following error message pops up:

> Uncaught Exception
>     Entity '...\Domain\Model\BaseClass' has no method
>     'Flow_Aop_Proxy_fixMethodsAndAdvicesArrayForDoctrineProxies' to be
>     registered as lifecycle callback.

So is it possible to use model inheritance in TYPO3 Flow?

Answer (score 1):

I found out one way to do it.

Just make your BaseClass abstract and add all the additional annotations like this:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class BaseClass {
```

And extend your models like that:

```
/**
 * @Flow\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 */
class SomeModel extends BaseClass{
```

The table of SomeModel will now have the attributes from the **BaseClass**. But BaseClass itself is not represented in the database schema.

Maybe you are also able to use traits for more complex solutions.